# Finding the type of underlying geometry from the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, mathematics

I am having a confusion regarding the type of geometry of a coordinate system, whether it is Euclidean or not. Intuitively if we consider the spherical polar coordinates, it is a Euclidean geometry since the sphere with unspecified radius is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but at the same time if we take the $S^2$ then it is locally a two dim space $\theta,\phi$ are specified. This is a non-Euclidean geometry globally, but locally Euclidean. If we see the form of the metric, for spherical polar coordinate, $$ ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2sin^2 \theta d\phi^2$$ which is a Euclidean metric.
Now for the surface if $S^2$, the metric reads
$$ ds^2=d\theta^2+sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$
How to see this metric corresponds to Non-Euclidean geometry?

One way to see (not incorporating the curvature tensor) is we would be able to find a linear transformation such a way the metric in Euclidean geometry may be reduced to the standard $\delta_{ij}$. This is not possible with non Eulcidean geometry. But how to find the transformation for the metric in spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: Calculate the Riemann tensor and see if it is zero. In general it can be hard to see if a metric is just the flat space metric in a different coordinate system so calculating the Riemann tensor and showing that it is zero is usually the best approach.

Comment: Since this is not a Lorentzian metric and has no time component it is presumably more maths than physics. You might consider asking it on the Maths SE instead of here.

Comment: if we find out the diffrence between two points infinitesimally close, or globally separated, the later is non Euclidean geometry. But the metric is same for both the cases I assume. Does that mean from the metric we can not find out the underlying gemtery?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: There is a related question: [Finding out "the" coordinate transformation to Minkowski metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460806/finding-out-the-coordinate-transformation-to-minkowski-metric).